# I'm looking for a simple way to generate code in python

Tags: python, scripting

So i essentially have a very large list of elements with similar names (c0,d0,c1,d1...etc)

and i was wondering if there was a simpler way that would essentially generate a script to generate each of these elements using strings

that would change a string "c0" into the actual variable c0

I would like to avoid using lists and would rather generate code, for reasons that are relevant to my project

Thanks guys!

Comment: And now you have me pondering what on earth those reasons could be, rather than a template engine for your code generation...

Comment: It goes without saying that if you have 100 similarly-named variables, then there's a high chance that there's a better way of solving the top-level problem...

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use code generation?  Code generation is probably not the best solution to this problem.

Comment: Are these elements actually collected in a Python list or some other data structure? Or are they just a hundred unrelated variables?

Comment: hmm... list elements don't have names, they have values.

Comment: @PeterGraham the reason is that i've given all of these variables ahead of time, and any way i could possible concatenate all of these into a list would take the same issue of either finding a way of generating the variable from a string, or doing a bunch of .appends which i would rather not do because of the large number of variables.

Comment: @toxotes they are a bunch of unrelated variables

Comment: @DanielImberman: If the variables unrelated, why are they similarly named?

Comment: @Bitwise would creating a dictionary run into the same issue? there are thousands of these variables (once again, these were there from the last guy, not my idea). any way that involves having to write out each individual variable could take hours of monotony.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski oh wait, sorry about that, I misunderstood what you meant by that. they are sort of related, but each of them works completely independently of eachother. the idea is that if we are in iteration 1 of the program we would use c1 and d1, and if we're in iteration 343, we would use c343 and d343. sorry about that my bad. if it were a small number of variables i could just set them to an array and then have an iteration parameter and say acces myarray[iteration]. but this is a really long list, and god help whoever thought to do it this way.

Comment: @DanielImberman A dict could work by using the 'index' of each variable as the key, like `c = {0:'a', 1:'b'}, d = {0:'A', 1:'b'}`. Then you could easily iterate through the range and compare c[x] == d[x]. Refactoring would save you a lot of hackishness down the line.

Comment: @toxotes interesting... this sounds like it might work, i just need to figure out how to work it in this situation. would it be something like c={0:c0, 1:c1}? because if that's the case i might be able to make a quick script to generate that code and just copy-paste it in....

Comment: Yeah, essentially. I'll flesh this out in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't take this the wrong way but I'm assuming you're new to Python based on the code in your question: it's not valid Python. There are tons of great Python tutorials all over the place -- read up on Python functions, built-ins, and the general philosophy. It's a really powerful language, but it looks like the script you inherited is ... not very Pythonic. Be sure not to learn the wrong things about the language from it.

So, ideally you want all these variables collected in some kind of data structure. Python has a bunch of different kinds of those.

If all you need to do is compare each index in a pair of fixed sets of data, you can get away with using tuples: these are ordered, immutable collections that imply a bit of structure. Let's say you have *n* pairs of data: you have two tuples, let's call them *c* and *d*, but it's obviously better to use descriptive names if you can. It would look like this:

```
c = (c0, c1, c2, ... cn)
d = (d0, d1, d2, ... dn)
```

And you'd compare them with something like this:

```
for i in range(len(c)):
    if c[i] == d[i]:
        print '%d: match' % i
    else:
        print '%d: no match' % i
```

(Two notes: len() finds the length of an object, range() creates an interable sequence -- where your question used len(), you'd want to use range() in Python. Also, the %d stuff is just string formatting.)

My assumption is that you need to more than that. For one thing, if the guy who wrote this thing thought it was a good idea to store data as hundreds of unique global variables, I wouldn't assume he thought to do things like ensure each variable exists and holds data, etc. at runtime So I'd personally use a dictionary in this case, because it gives you a bit more flexibility.

Each dict is a collection of key:value pairs. Dicts are unordered, so you can't directly compare the first item in each one -- there is no first item. What you *can* do is use a sequence of integers as the keys, and then iterate through the range of that sequence. And you can do things like retrieve a value with a default, so you won't crash the program if c64 never got declared:

```
c = {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'r'}
d = {0:'a', 1:'B', 2:None, 3:'d'}
```

And then something like:

```
for i in range(len(c)):
    if c.get(i, 'No value') == d.get(i, 'No value'):
        print '%d: match' % i
    else:
        print '%d: no match' % i
```

Though you'd usually retrieve data from a dict like `c[4]` or `d['apple']`. Get() lets us use a default value ('No value') in case some value of *i* is missing.

(Another assumption: that each pair of data represents some real data relationship, so the number of the iteration is semantically a label as much as it is an index. To my mind, keys should usually be labels rather than values themselves.)

What you've suggested in your comment, collecting the existing variables into one of these structures, would work fine. Just open up Notepad++ and do some smart search/replace with your source, should take you ten minutes. You'd end up with `c = (c0, c1, c2, etc)` or `c = {0:c0, 1:c1, etc}`, or something different if you find another structure that fits your needs. But what I really think you should do is refactor the entire script, so that the data you're comparing is stored in some kind of object that reflects what it is and how you're using it. Python will let you work real magic here: with a bit of legwork, you could be doing something as simple as `c == d`, finding the joint or disjoint sets of *c* and *d*, manipulating data values at certain iterations, or whatever you need.

Comment: thanks man! I'm semi new to python, and i actually know that wasnt proper python, i originally had it written correctly and i realized that it wasn't conveying the idea that i was trying to convey. I think that writing a dictionary would probably be my best choice here. thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielImberman Great, I'm glad that's put you on the right track. I'd suggest editing your question a bit to reflect that you're really looking to deal with a script that does a poor job of unorganizing data, rather than code generation per se. You'll probably get some more pointers on how to fix things.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), and [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

If your variables are local to the function you could this.  If your variables are global use `globals()` instead.

```
for i in len(100):
    first_name = "c{0}".format(i)
    second_name = "d{0}".format(i)
    if(locals()[first_name] == locals()[second_name]):
        print("hello")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the eval function:

```
for i in xrange(100):
    if eval('c%d' % i) == eval('d%d' % i):
        print "Hello!"
```